# Closing the main menu on mouse out

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

we are using default nav-bar of bootstrap in our website [mihanmag](https://mihanmag.com)

I want to close the menu, when mouse go out of it. can anyone help me?

Comment: Looks like spam. Why don't you post related code here as [mcve]?

Comment: Have you written even a single line of code about it? Might be an attempt to gain some traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code.

Remove following js:

```
$('.dropdown').hover(function () {
    $('.dropdown.open').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("open");
    });
    $(this).addClass("open");
});
```

and just use the simple following css to do this

```
li.dropdown:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```